# Writing xml using php soap library

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have issue and I don't know how to correctly write complex SOAP like this:

```
<entry>
    <key>KEY</key>
    <value xsi:type="ns1:Param">
        <oid>OID</oid>
    </value>
</entry>
```

Looks like I'm almost done, but I have error like this:

> "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'oid' property"

Below is my current code:

```
$key = new SoapVar('key', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'key');
$oid = new SoapVar('oid', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'oid');
$value = new SoapVar([$oid], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'Param', 'URL', 'value');
$entry = new SoapVar([$key, $value], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'entry');
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: This is just a comment. But you might want to re-think using SOAP. It is really outdated and you might have a hard time working with it. I suggest looking into REST APIs, which can be built with alot of librairies and is very commonly used.

Comment: Yeah, I know we just have a legacy code which still uses XML :/

Comment: @Nicolas: SOAP and REST have different uses: https://raygun.com/blog/soap-vs-rest-vs-json/ . There's no reason to scrap SOAP because it's an "old protocol".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed using this code!:

```
$key = new SoapVar('KEY', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'key');
$value = new SoapVar(['oid' => 'OID'], XSD_ANYTYPE, 'Param', 'URL', 'value');
$entry = new SoapVar([$key, $value], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'entry');
```